# Grease Pencil Armature Partial Binding

Tags: armature, weight-painting, grease-pencil

I'm trying to bind grease pencil to an armature. The armature is very 3d and the grease pencil follows along in similar fashion aka it's not on a 2d plane like many use it.

Tried using a lattice as a proxy & couldn't get that method to work in the slightest so I switched to just trying to bind it directly to the armature with automatic weights. Partial success, some of it binds and some of it doesn't.

I'm completely perplexed how some of it could bind properly while other parts haven't. Anyhow I get to deleting the bits that aren't rebinding properly and remaking the, in the hopes that it'll bind right on second try. And this is where it gets really bizzare, because no matter how many times I remake it, it's the exact same spots that won't bind and if I add some other lines in new places it's like 50/50 if it will bind and if it won't, it won't on any future tries in that same place.

Anyway, was hoping someone could shed some light on if there's any thing I can do to get grease pencil to bind properly to an armature. Thx in advance.

The Image below is what it looks like when I move the hand upwards somewhat with the partial bind.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many of the weight paint features including binding with Automatic weights are not yet fully implemented nor work as expected.

That being said, it is still possible to weight paint the bone influences after binding with automatic weights to correct parts and fully bind others points which were too far away from the bone head to receive any influence.

Here's an interesting link about the unpredictable nature of weight binding grease pencil objects to an Armature which might be of some use.

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/56693#issuecomment-520000